# System.CalloutException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"

Tags: apex, integration, configuration, rest

While trying to call REST web service, i am getting callout exception while doing authentication.
follow is the Code spinet, ulr and token is updated for this example.

```
Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
// ** Getting Security Token from STS
String Url = 'https://[namesapec].accesscontrol.windows.net/WRAPv0.9/';
req.setEndpoint(Url);
req.setMethod('POST');           
req.setBody('wrap_name=test&wrap_password=N4LGx2cNPTEDFC6K0Wo4+/pTbNjcHLDSASDNnybnykc=&wrap_scope=http://[namesapec].servicebus.windows.net/SampleQueue');          req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
// Getting error here           
 HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
 String result = res.getBody();
 system.debug('RESULT ::: '+result);
```

I am following [Connecting Force.com to on Premises Resources, Part 2](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Connecting_Force.com_to_Azure_Service_Bus_Part2) blog to achieve Azure integration with sfdc

Answer (score 7):

This has to be resolved at the client end to which you are making the webservice callout .

Ask your other Team who have created that webservice and check whether they have white-listed salesforce IP's in their proxy .The Proxy here is not allowing your request to reach the exact end point and its filtering request from the SFDC.

http://www.salesforcegeneral.com/salesforce-articles/ip-whitelists-for-salesforce.html

Comment: Hi All,I have same exception Can someone help me,See the link: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/41440/system-calloutexception-you-have-uncommitted-work-pending